# embedded system vs real time system i can't get the difference

Tags: embedded

Till now I used to think that embedded and real time systems are same. But when I was asked in an interview that what the difference is between the two, I was scared. I can't even get proper answer by searching in web.

Comment: Your question is too vague and general, and is not really a programming problem in my opinion.

Comment: i can't find the ans in web

Comment: After less than 5 seconds of googling... https://bogdangradinaru.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/what-is-the-difference-between-embedded-system-and-real-time-system/

Comment: difference is not clear!

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski - that link is no use - some other student will have already copy/pasted that info.  OP wants you to rewrite it to avoid plagiarism detection.

Comment: Special purpose; hard dead line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a poor question perhaps since they are not mutually exclusive; an embedded system may be real-time or it may not.  One term describes the physical embodiment of a system, the other describes its performance and response characteristics.

*Embedded system* describes a system that contains one or more software programmable devices but which is not itself a *general purpose* computer.  Such a system typically has a fixed, single application rather than end-user selected and loaded software (which would make it *general purpose*).

However "embedded" covers a wide spectrum of systems and is not always easy to define; for example if you were writing the UMTS code for a smartphone, you might reasonably be regarded as an embedded developer, if you were writing *Flappy Angry Birds 2.0* for that same phone however, you would not - so a smartphone may be both an embedded system and general purpose computer - depending on your view point.  Similarly a hand-held games console's system software is embedded; the games themselves are not I would say.

A real-time system describes a system with deterministic low latency response to input events.  An embedded system may be "real-time, or it might not.  I would normally use the term "*real-time embedded system*" to be clear.